# How to create a private project repository (git based) on IBM JazzHub using Commandline?

Tags: git, command-line, ibm-cloud, devops

Is there any way we can create a JazzHub Project on IBM Bluemix Jazz Hub using command-line?

There is a tool called [Bluemix LiveSync](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/develop/bluemixlive.html) executed with `bl create`. It is supported on MacOS and Windows Only. Is there any way we can use git based tooling to create a IBM Bluemix JazzHub project.

Please help. thanks.

**I am getting following exception on Mac and I am unable to create a private project.**

```
bash $ **bl create -n testingcustom** 

IBM Bluemix Live Sync CLI V1.0.7 (c) 2015 IBM Corp.

Fetching Bluemix info ...2016-02-22 22:33:41.009 bl[22874:381799] ***
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
'*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty
array'
*** First throw call stack: (   0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff847a003c __exceptionPreprocess + 172  1   libobjc.A.dylib   
0x00007fff8d16d76e objc_exception_throw + 43    2   CoreFoundation      
0x00007fff846691e4 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 260   3   bl         
0x0000000102ae906d -[Create execute] + 3952     4   bl                   
0x0000000102ae27fa -[Command run:] + 253    5   bl                      
0x0000000102ad54c3 main + 385   6   libdyld.dylib                      
0x00007fff8d39b5c9 start + 1    7   ???                                
0x000000000000000a 0x0 + 10 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
uncaught exception of type NSException Abort trap: 6
```

OSX version : 10.10.5 (14F27)

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this problem, too.

- Before trying to create project by using command-line, you should
  login jazzhub(https://hub.jazz.net/).
- Test your account by creating a project in jazzhub.
- If asked, provide an alias name.

After completing these steps, try to create project by using command-line. This solution provided to me after opening a ticket for Bluemix support team and it worked for me.